# Check if div contains text to add class in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check if a particular div contains a particular word then it shoould add a class to it. e.g if div has Ballet it should add class ballet, if it has yoga, it should add class yoga, etc.

Below is the code I am trying but it doesn't seem to work:

```js
$(".am-event").each(function() {

  if ($(this).text().trim() == "Ballet") {
    $(this).addClass('ballet')
  } else if ($(this).text().trim() == "Yoga") {
    $(this).addClass('yoga')
  } else {

  }

});
```

```css
.am-event {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.ballet {
  background:red;
}

.yoga {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="am-event-22" class="am-event" style="pointer-events: all;">
  <div class="am-event-data">
    <div class="am-event-info">
      <div class="am-event-title">Ballet
              <span class="am-event-booking-status open">Open</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="am-event-23" class="am-event" style="pointer-events: all;">
  <div class="am-event-data">
    <div class="am-event-info">
      <div class="am-event-title">Yoga
              <span class="am-event-booking-status open">Open</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="am-event-24" class="am-event" style="pointer-events: all;">
  <div class="am-event-data">
    <div class="am-event-info">
      <div class="am-event-title">Ballet
              <span class="am-event-booking-status open">Open</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `indexOf` method to check whether the string is present in a sentence or not.

`trim` will remove all the leading and trailing white spaces and new line characters but that will return the complete sentence, like `"Ballet Open"`, `"Yoga Open"` etc. You have toc heck whether the particular string is there or not. For that you have to use `indexOf` method, that will return the starting index of that particular word if exist or -1 if that word is not there in that string.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".am-event").each(function () {
    if ($(this).text().trim().indexOf("Ballet") !== -1) {
      $(this).addClass("ballet");
    } else if ($(this).text().trim().indexOf("Yoga") !== -1) {
      $(this).addClass("yoga");
    } else {
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.am-event {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.ballet {
  background: red;
}

.yoga {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="am-event-22" class="am-event" style="pointer-events: all">
  <div class="am-event-data">
    <div class="am-event-info">
      <div class="am-event-title">
        Ballet <span class="am-event-booking-status open">Open</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="am-event-23" class="am-event" style="pointer-events: all">
  <div class="am-event-data">
    <div class="am-event-info">
      <div class="am-event-title">
        Yoga <span class="am-event-booking-status open">Open</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="am-event-24" class="am-event" style="pointer-events: all">
  <div class="am-event-data">
    <div class="am-event-info">
      <div class="am-event-title">
        Ballet <span class="am-event-booking-status open">Open</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This may help you.**

```
            /* Create function */
            function addClassByKeyword(keyword, key_class){
                $(".am-event").each(function() {
                    
                    var item_text = $(this).find('.am-event-title').text();
                    
                    var keyword_pattern = new RegExp(keyword, "gi");
                    var search_word = item_text.match(keyword_pattern);

                    if (search_word && search_word.length !== 0) {
                        $(this).addClass(key_class);
                    }
                    
                });
            }

            /* Call the function */
            addClassByKeyword("Yoga", "yoga");
            addClassByKeyword("Ballet", "ballet");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the structure is the same (type of class / then status) - you can simply get teh first word of the text content - convert it to lower case and add it directly to the class list.

Just note that when you use text() - it will return the text of the entire node - in this case the included span - this is probably why your initial code wasn't working.

I would not do an if/else or a indexOf() check or even a ternary - I would simply get the text, split it to get just the first word, convert it to lower case and then add it as a class to the div.

So this will give"ballet" or "yoga" as the first word which is then added to the classList of the div.

```js
$(".am-event").each(function() {
 const type = $(this).text().trim().split(' ')[0].toLowerCase();
 $(this).addClass(type);
 console.log(type);
});
```

```css
.am-event {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.ballet {
  background:red;
}

.yoga {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="am-event-22" class="am-event" style="pointer-events: all;">
  <div class="am-event-data">
    <div class="am-event-info">
      <div class="am-event-title">Ballet
              <span class="am-event-booking-status open">Open</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="am-event-23" class="am-event" style="pointer-events: all;">
  <div class="am-event-data">
    <div class="am-event-info">
      <div class="am-event-title">Yoga
              <span class="am-event-booking-status open">Open</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="am-event-24" class="am-event" style="pointer-events: all;">
  <div class="am-event-data">
    <div class="am-event-info">
      <div class="am-event-title">Ballet
              <span class="am-event-booking-status open">Open</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```